# MYSQL/Laravel : convert a WHERE into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, variables, where-clause

I've got a query allowing me to filter some projects.

You don't have to understand it to help me.

```
$payments->whereExists(function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate){
                    // We must browse the projects to know if there was a project created BEFORE the project ^ and with different id

                    $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('project as oldProjects')
                      ->whereRaw('oldProjects.deleted = 0')
                      ->whereRaw('oldProjects.id != project.id')
                      ->whereRaw('oldProjects.date_entered < project.date_entered')

                      ->whereExists(function($query2){
                            // We have to check if the project found belongs to the specified account
                            $query2->select(DB::raw(1))
                            ->from('accounts_project_1_c as oldProjectsAccount')
                            ->where('oldProjects.deleted', 0)
                            ->whereRaw('oldProjectsAccount.accounts_project_1project_idb = oldProjects.id')
                            ->whereRaw('oldProjectsAccount.accounts_project_1accounts_ida = accounts_pm7_payments7_1_c.accounts_pm7_payments7_1accounts_ida');
                       });
                });
```

So this is a WHERE, that will help me to get only projects from returning clients (a previous project existed before).

I would like to add this to another request, but as a value (returning = 1, or returning = 0) and no longer as a WHERE.

Just FYI, here is the request in which I would like to add this variable:

```
$trustLogsQuotes = DB::table('trlog_trustaccountlog')
            ->select(
                'trlog_trustaccountlog.id as trlog_id',
                'quotes.id as quote_id',
                'quotes.name as quote_name',
                'quotes_cstm.quote_type_c')
            ->leftJoin('trlog_trustaccountlog_project_c', 'trlog_trustaccountlog_project_c.trlog_trustaccountlog_projecttrlog_trustaccountlog_idb', '=', 'trlog_trustaccountlog.id')
            ->leftJoin('project', 'trlog_trustaccountlog_project_c.trlog_trustaccountlog_projectproject_ida', '=', 'project.id')
            ->leftJoin('project_quotes_1_c', 'project_quotes_1_c.project_quotes_1project_ida', '=', 'project.id')
            ->leftJoin('quotes', 'quotes.id', '=', 'project_quotes_1_c.project_quotes_1quotes_idb')
            ->leftJoin('quotes_cstm', 'quotes_cstm.id_c', '=', 'quotes.id')
            ->where('trlog_trustaccountlog.transfer_date_c', '>=', $startDate)
            ->where('trlog_trustaccountlog.transfer_date_c', '<', $endDate)
            ->where('trlog_trustaccountlog.transfer_type_c', 'Transfer')
            ->where('trlog_trustaccountlog.deleted', 0)
            ->where('trlog_trustaccountlog_project_c.deleted', 0)
            ->where('project.deleted', 0)
            ->where('project_quotes_1_c.deleted', 0)
            ->where('quotes.deleted', 0)
            ->get();
```

I really don't know how to convert it. Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Comment: I am not sure if you want to reuse the where part in two places or this is a database related question and you want to have something like an if-x-then-1 in the resulting SELECT statement.

Comment: It's the second option, if-x-then-1, but the logic is currently set in a WHERE (cf first request)

Comment: Mysql supports IF and CASE-WHEN-statements, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

This is how you can use it with Laravel:
$query->select("operations.*",\DB::raw("SUM(if(interviews.valid=2, 1, 0)) AS invalid"));

Comment: Thanks a lot @herrjeh42, I found a way thanks to your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, here is my working result.

```
DB::raw('IF (EXISTS (
                                SELECT 1 FROM project as oldProjects 
                                WHERE oldProjects.deleted = 0 
                                AND oldProjects.id != project.id
                                AND oldProjects.date_entered < project.date_entered
                                AND EXISTS(
                                        SELECT 1 FROM accounts_project_1_c as oldProjectsAccount
                                        WHERE oldProjects.deleted = 0
                                        AND oldProjectsAccount.accounts_project_1project_idb = oldProjects.id
                                        AND oldProjectsAccount.accounts_project_1accounts_ida = account_id
                                    )
                                ), 1, 0) as returning'),
```